# Extremely slow desktop and laggy. Need help with graphics driver

Tags: drivers, 13.04, intel-graphics, tablet, lincroft

I am a fresh newbie Ubuntu user and I just installed my first Ubuntu 13.04 onto my HP Slate 2. I did a liveCD on my USB drive and installed everything perfectly fine...nice and smooth, not a trace of lag.

Then I rebooted using Ubuntu itself on the computer, it was extremely slow and laggy. Icons or any buttons doesn't trigger right away, the performance of the entire thing looks like either 0.25 fps to 1 fps.

My HP Slate 2 information:

- Processor: Intel Atom Z670 1.5Ghz
- Memory Ram: 2.0 GB
- Videocard: Intel GMA 600 (PowerVr SGX535)
- SolidStateDrive(SSD): 32GB

I tried installing the Intel Linux graphics driver and it failed to install because it said I don't have any Intel based graphics card. Well...I do as you see above.

What can I do? I can't get on the Internet on it, I'm using my primary computer (Windows 7) to do all the searchings and put the files onto the USB to move it over to my tablet.

Simply...I don't get it...using liveCD on USB, it was all nice and smooth...then after the installation...BOOM! Slow, laggy, and etc.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am running Xubuntu 13.04 on my HP Slate 2. I still have problems with the GMA600, for example it runs smooth but the HDMI output does not work. Consider Xubuntu 13.04, it is basically Ubuntu but on a Xfce platform that is leaner and faster!